# How do I bring the Z value to attribute table?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, elevation, xyz

I have a shapefile exported from a hydraulics software that I use. The file is exported as polylines. I convert it to a point layer using the "Extract Nodes" function. The remaining piece of information I need is the elevation (z value) of each point. I know they exist because I can see them, in the Vertex editor and the wkt_geom column when I copy paste to Excel. I see the "z()" function but can't figure out the appropriate syntax.

I tried this: `z(geom_from_wkt( [shapefile_name]))`

Is there a function, or a work-around, similar to the $x and $y functions to extract the z value from the geometry and display it in the attribute table?

I am talking about a point shapefile, and using QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following expression :

```
z($geometry)
```

The help says "z(geom)" geom being a **point geometry** ... so i don't think there's any benefit trying to play with wkt expressions ....

Comment: That worked Thank you!
I had tried that already but wouldn't you know when i bring it down to 1000 pts instead of 37,000 it works just fine.